# Is there a function to check if the given string pattern in valid

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-function

I need an Oracle function to check if the given input string is valid.

For eg. input string is `50-100,145,153`

The function should check

1. `num1` < `num2` in `num1-num2`
2. the string pattern should always be `num1-num2,num3,num4`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function, but you can use regular expressions. For example (only the first row is valid):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '50-100,145,153' from dual union all
  3     select '50-49,145,153'  from dual union all
  4     select 'a-2,b,200'      from dual union all
  5     select '10-20,30'       from dual union all
  6     select '1,2-3,4'        from dual
  7    )
  8  select col
  9  from test
 10  where regexp_like(col, '^\d+-\d+,\d+,\d+$')
 11    and to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 1)) < to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2));

COL
--------------
50-100,145,153

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach:

```sql
with test (col) as
  (select '50-100,145,153' from dual union all  -- ok
   select '50-49,145,153'  from dual union all
   select 'a-2,b,200'      from dual union all
   select '10-20,30'       from dual union all  -- ok
   select '1,2-3,4'        from dual union all  -- ok
   -- additional test values:
   select '1,2,3,7-8,100,120-130,200'  from dual union all -- ok
   select '1-3,7-8,120-130,200'        from dual union all -- ok
   select '1,2,3,8-7,100,120-130,200'  from dual union all -- nope
   select '1,2,3,7-8,100,130-120,200'  from dual union all -- nope
   select '1,2,3,7-8,100,,,120-z,200'  from dual union all -- nope
   select '1,2,3,7-8,100,,,120,200'    from dual           -- nope
  )
select col
from test
where regexp_like(col, '^(((\d+-\d+)|\d+),?)+$')
  and (select 
          count(*)
       from dual
         where to_number(regexp_substr(col,'(\d+)-(\d+)',1,level,null,1))
             > to_number(regexp_substr(col,'(\d+)-(\d+)',1,level,null,2))
       connect by level<=regexp_count(col,'(\d+)-(\d+)')
      ) = 0;
```

1. `regexp_like(col, '^(((\d+-\d+)|\d+),?)+$')` checks that `col` consist only from 2 patterns: `\d+-\d+` and `\d+` with comma between them.
2. in the subquery we check if there is `num1>num2`